# VBA Concatenation returns number even though Dimensioned as String

Tags: vba, excel

I am running a concatenation through a `Do While` Loop and the output is supposed to look like this:

51000000160001493123

Instead my code is chopping off the last 4 numbers and displaying this:

5.1E+17, and when I click on the cell it shows 
510000016001493000

How can I change my code to force the output to a `string` type?

My Code is as follows:

```
Concat = sh.Cells(RowNum, ColB) & sh.Cells(RowNum, ColC) & sh.Cells(RowNum, ColF) & sh.Cells(RowNum, ColM) & sh.Cells(RowNum, ColO)
sh.Cells(RowNum, ColAA) = Concat
```

> Note: `sh` refers to the `worksheet`, and When I hover over the concat variable in the debug window, the result is correct

Additionally I also have tried adding in the `Format` ?method? and have not gotten anywhere with it

```
 Concat = sh.Cells(RowNum, ColB) & sh.Cells(RowNum, ColC) & sh.Cells(RowNum, ColF) & sh.Cells(RowNum, ColM) & sh.Cells(RowNum, ColO)
Result = Format(PrimaryLookupConcat)
sh.Cells(RowNum, ColAA) = Result
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need do the changes in cell format before inserting the result into it:

```
with sh.Cells(RowNum, ColAA)
    .numberformat = "@"
    .value = sh.Cells(RowNum, ColB) & _
             sh.Cells(RowNum, ColC) & _
             sh.Cells(RowNum, ColF) & _
             sh.Cells(RowNum, ColM) & _
             sh.Cells(RowNum, ColO)
end with
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue isn't with the VBA code, it's with how Excel interprets the Value if the cell format isn't set to Text.

You can either set the format:

```
sh.Cells.NumberFormat = "@"
sh.Cells(RowNum, ColAA).Value = Concat
```

...or append a single quote to the start to force it to be evaluated as text:

```
sh.Cells(RowNum, ColAA).Value = "'" & Concat
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that excel is converting the text to a number when it gets pasted into the cell and excel storesall numbers as 15 digit floating point numbers (see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/245109/add-more-than-20-digits-in-excel-without-an-exponential-sign))

One easy solution is to change your line to the following:

```
sh.Cells(RowNum, ColAA) = "'" & Concat
```

This will force the value into a string and keep all of the digits.

If you don't want the apostrophe in the cell, you need to set the format of the cell to "Text."  If it is set as "General" Excel will automatically convert the contenated string into a number.  You can do this in VBA if you want, but it'd be easiest to just set the whole column to "Text" format.  Then just use the original code you had.